# Delegation to Subdns doesn't work

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

I recently tried to setup a DNS. The checking tool tells me that some A records are missing. But I think I did. 
 
Zonefile:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 2D
.       IN      SOA     ns1. root.ns1. (
                        2016052404    ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                3H      ; NX (TTL Negativ Cache)
)
.                               IN      NS      ns1.
ns1.                            IN      A       192.168.107.2
at.                             IN      NS      ns1.at.
ns1.at.                         IN      A       192.168.107.3
jp.                             IN      NS      ns1.jp.
ns1.jp.                         IN      A       192.168.107.5
```

```sh
user@dns1:/etc/bind# sudo named-checkzone . db.zonefile
zone ./IN: at/NS 'ns1.at' (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)
zone ./IN: jp/NS 'ns1.jp' (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)
zone ./IN: loaded serial 2016052404
OK
```

/etc/bind/named-conf.local

```
zone "." {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.zonefile";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.0.168.192";
};
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
search .
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This file is for testing/learning purposes, right?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `sudo named-checkzone -i local . db.zonefile`

from [named-checkzone man page](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/man.named-checkzone.html):

> OPTIONS
>
> ...
>
> `-i mode`
>
> Perform post-load zone integrity checks. Possible modes are "full" (default), "full-sibling", "local", "local-sibling" and "none".
>   ...
>   Mode "full" checks that delegation NS records refer to A or AAAA
>   record (both in-zone and out-of-zone hostnames). It also checks that
>   glue address records in the zone match those advertised by the child.
>   Mode "local" only checks NS records which refer to in-zone hostnames
>   or that some required glue exists, that is when the nameserver is in a
>   child zone.
>   ...

Without `-i local` option, upstream DNS server (defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`) will also be checked, so for example with 8.8.8.8 I get the following result (which is expected):

```
[root@localhost ~]# named-checkzone . foo.db
zone ./IN: at/NS 'ns1.at' extra GLUE A record (192.168.107.3)
zone ./IN: at/NS 'ns1.at' missing GLUE A record (176.28.37.75)
zone ./IN: at/NS 'ns1.at' missing GLUE AAAA record (2a01:488:42:1000:b01c:254b:fffe:f92a)
zone ./IN: getaddrinfo(ns1.jp) failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
zone ./IN: loaded serial 2016052404
OK
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: hmm, so the issue may lie in the /etc/resolv.conf file? I have edited it previosuly that it only contains my local configured dns, maybe something there is wrong. Could you please take a look? I have added the other files i have edited above too.